# how to filter column like wise in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    **OS** 
..............  
   Window 
     NULL
    NULL
    Android

select * from Device_Filter_Scan_View 
where  

 (os like 
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE('iOS-5',''),'%') or os is null)
```

this is my query i want filter data like this manner if we pass null in Os then it should give all record including null one also if we  pass iOS-5 then its give only iOS-5 but currently in null case it give all record but when i pass iOS-5 it give iOS-5 also null one also please suggest me where am doing wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
where (os like concat('%', $param, '%') or $param is null)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'iOS' in 'where clause'
 exception i am getting  when i excute this select * from Device_Filter_Scan_View 
where  
 (os like concat('%', iOS, '%') or iOS is null)

Comment: @MakleeLee . . . Pass the parameter in properly as a *query parameter* rather than munging the query string.